# Defining the same price to all WooCommerce Products

Tags: mysql, plugins

All of my products on my site are $1 and during an import I did using WooCommerce import it didn't save all the _regular_price & _sale_price values, so there is no way for the user to buy that product.

Is there a mysql query that can go through and apply a value to all of the nulls to the $1 value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are not familiar with WordPress [Bulk Edit](http://codex.wordpress.org/Posts_Screen#Bulk_Edit).

Change the `Screen Options` to show all the products you have (if there are too many this can be slow, and is better to do it following some 100/200 product per page).

[image: woocommerce products screen options]

Select all the products, select `Edit` in the Bulk Edit dropdown and `Apply`.

Now you can change a batch of product details.

[image: woocommerce products bulk edit]
<sup>*^ click to enlarge ^*</sup>

Comment: Awesome! And I was trying to do it through the database lol.

Comment: I didn't know that until now. Thanks a lot.